# Umount NFS volume after a service stopped

Tags: debian, mount, fstab

I have a error when a restart my server because it try to umount a volume which is still used by a service.

How can I edit my fstab entry to stop the service before umounting the volume ?

My fstab looks like :

```
192.168.0.3:/mnt/nfs/vol /mnt/vol nfs defaults 0 0
```

And I tried:

```
192.168.0.3:/mnt/nfs/vol /mnt/vol nfs x-systemd.after=my.service 0 0
```

But the system mount the volume after the service that is not purpose

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.